# TFS Build 2013 can't select mstest

Tags: tfs, mstest

On my tfs if I select the default template (tfvstemplate.12.xaml).
I wan't to run mstest for my unittest's but i can't select a other test runner

I have installed tfs 2013 and visual studio ultimate 2013.

The selection field is just disabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the 2013 build template Microsoft has defaulted to the new Agile Test Runner and no longer supports the selection of the old test runner for 2013 (12.0) templates.

When you select a 2012 or 2010 build template (10.0 or 11.0), Team Build will still run using the MsTest runner. If you customize the 2013 template to use the old Run Tests activity it will still run tests using the MsTest runner. You need to run these older templates against a Team Build server that's still running Team Build 2010 or 2012.

The new Test Runner can execute MsTest based tests, but doesn't support the old Test Settings files. Instead it uses the new Run Settings files instead. The next version of TFS and Team Build will most likely drop support for the old test runner completely.

Comment: Thank You, I will start using the visual studio test runner